# click on button to go next tab otherwise not allowd to press next tab

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I am trying to prevent the user clicking on the un-selected tab before clicking on the button in the current tab. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
           <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li><a href="#home" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled" data-toggle="tab" >Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Write Here Tab Home Part

                            <button class="tab-button" type="submit">Hello</button>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Write Here Tab Profile Part</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Write Here Tab Messages Part</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Write Here Tab Settings Part</div>
                </div>
```

js:

```
<!-- Move to other tabs by clicking on the button -->
<script>

$(".tab-button").click
(
    function()
    {
        $('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').tab('show');

        $("[class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled']").removeClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");
        $('.nav-tabs li:eq(1) a').addClass("btn btn-large btn-block btn-success disabled");
    }
);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to prevent the click event:

```
$(".nav-tabs li a[data-toggle=tab]").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `)`.

Comment: I couldn't get this approach to work on my own set of jQuery tabs, but noticed that I don't have a data-toggle attribute? Is this to do with the version of jQuery UI?

Comment: No that's not so important as it ensures the li element is a tab handler. and your code looks like twitter bootstrap tabs code.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the DOM of your script. The event should be assigned to the "a" element. Try this updated code.

Comment: Did you test this? I don't think it works. It's the approach I tried initially.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what exactly you want to achieve here, but you can override the default tab navigation behavior.

```
$('.nav-tabs').tabs({ event: '' });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .disabledTab{
pointer-events: none;
 }


<li class="disabledTab"></li>
//please use this class disabledTab to prevent click.
```